# How TeX creates DVI without reading TFM file?

Tags: fonts, texlive, plain-tex, format-files, dvipdfmx

My setup: TeX Live, version 2014.20141024-2 (packaged with Debian 8 Jessie)

Consider test.tex

```
A
\bye
```

```
$ tex -ini '\input plain \dump'
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (INITEX)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/base/plain.tex
Preloading the plain format: codes, registers, parameters, fonts, more fonts,
macros, math definitions, output routines, hyphenation
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex))
Beginning to dump on file plain.fmt
 (preloaded format=plain 2015.4.17)
2021 strings of total length 29135
4990 memory locations dumped; current usage is 110&4877
926 multiletter control sequences
\font\nullfont=nullfont
\font\tenrm=cmr10
\font\preloaded=cmr9
\font\preloaded=cmr8
\font\sevenrm=cmr7
\font\preloaded=cmr6
\font\fiverm=cmr5
\font\teni=cmmi10
\font\preloaded=cmmi9
\font\preloaded=cmmi8
\font\seveni=cmmi7
\font\preloaded=cmmi6
\font\fivei=cmmi5
\font\tensy=cmsy10
\font\preloaded=cmsy9
\font\preloaded=cmsy8
\font\sevensy=cmsy7
\font\preloaded=cmsy6
\font\fivesy=cmsy5
\font\tenex=cmex10
\font\preloaded=cmss10
\font\preloaded=cmssq8
\font\preloaded=cmssi10
\font\preloaded=cmssqi8
\font\tenbf=cmbx10
\font\preloaded=cmbx9
\font\preloaded=cmbx8
\font\sevenbf=cmbx7
\font\preloaded=cmbx6
\font\fivebf=cmbx5
\font\tentt=cmtt10
\font\preloaded=cmtt9
\font\preloaded=cmtt8
\font\preloaded=cmsltt10
\font\tensl=cmsl10
\font\preloaded=cmsl9
\font\preloaded=cmsl8
\font\tenit=cmti10
\font\preloaded=cmti9
\font\preloaded=cmti8
\font\preloaded=cmti7
\font\preloaded=cmu10
\font\preloaded=cmmib10
\font\preloaded=cmbsy10
\font\preloaded=cmcsc10
\font\preloaded=cmssbx10
\font\preloaded=cmdunh10
\font\preloaded=cmr7 at 14.51799pt
\font\preloaded=cmtt10 at 14.4pt
\font\preloaded=cmssbx10 at 14.4pt
\font\preloaded=manfnt
14787 words of font info for 50 preloaded fonts
14 hyphenation exceptions
Hyphenation trie of length 6075 has 181 ops out of 35111
  181 for language 0
No pages of output.
Transcript written on plain.log.
```

Remove TFM file from search path:

```
$ sudo mv `kpsewhich cmr10.tfm` /tmp/
```

This works OK. Why?

```
$ tex -fmt plain -progname tex test.tex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (preloaded format=plain)
(./test.tex [1] )
Output written on test.dvi (1 page, 208 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

This gives error, as expected:

```
$ dvipdfmx test.dvi
test.dvi -> test.pdf
[1
dvipdfmx:fatal: Unable to find TFM file "cmr10".

Output file removed.
```

This works OK. Why?

```
$ xdvi test.dvi
```

Answer (score 10):

The tfm file for cmr10 has been read and the relevant data is dumped in the format, and is not read again. You can see all the fonts that were read in your initex run.

The tfm for all these are loaded into the format:

```
\font\tenrm=cmr10
\font\preloaded=cmr9
\font\preloaded=cmr8
\font\sevenrm=cmr7
\font\preloaded=cmr6
\font\fiverm=cmr5
\font\teni=cmmi10
\font\preloaded=cmmi9
\font\preloaded=cmmi8
\font\seveni=cmmi7
\font\preloaded=cmmi6
\font\fivei=cmmi5
\font\tensy=cmsy10
\font\preloaded=cmsy9
\font\preloaded=cmsy8
\font\sevensy=cmsy7
\font\preloaded=cmsy6
\font\fivesy=cmsy5
\font\tenex=cmex10
\font\preloaded=cmss10
\font\preloaded=cmssq8
\font\preloaded=cmssi10
\font\preloaded=cmssqi8
\font\tenbf=cmbx10
\font\preloaded=cmbx9
\font\preloaded=cmbx8
\font\sevenbf=cmbx7
\font\preloaded=cmbx6
\font\fivebf=cmbx5
\font\tentt=cmtt10
\font\preloaded=cmtt9
\font\preloaded=cmtt8
\font\preloaded=cmsltt10
\font\tensl=cmsl10
\font\preloaded=cmsl9
\font\preloaded=cmsl8
\font\tenit=cmti10
\font\preloaded=cmti9
\font\preloaded=cmti8
\font\preloaded=cmti7
\font\preloaded=cmu10
\font\preloaded=cmmib10
\font\preloaded=cmbsy10
\font\preloaded=cmcsc10
\font\preloaded=cmssbx10
\font\preloaded=cmdunh10
\font\preloaded=cmr7 at 14.51799pt
\font\preloaded=cmtt10 at 14.4pt
\font\preloaded=cmssbx10 at 14.4pt
\font\preloaded=manfnt
```

Comment: Just to be complete: where is it documented? And what about xdvi?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The TeXBook documents the plain format and does explicitly mention the fact that fonts are preloaded (and the use of the `\preloaded` csname there that loads the fonts without defining a name for them. Or the `plain.tex` file that you used to make the format has the comment `% Fonts assigned to \preloaded are not part of "plain TeX",
% but they are preloaded so that other format packages can use them.
% For example, if another set of macros says "\font\ninerm=cmr9",
% TeX will not have to reload the font metric information for cmr9.`

Comment: @IgorLiferenko dvi drivers often (but not always) need the tfm metrics to lay out glyphs correctly so they need to find the tfm file, the fact that the information is in the plain format file doesn't help them.

Answer (score 6):

Your test is not conclusive. Consider the file

```
\nopagenumbers
\font\ptm=ptmr8r
\ptm a
\bye
```

and compile it with `tex -recorder`, so a `.fls` file will be created containing information about the loaded files; I only removed the first line that reports the working directory

```
PWD <not shown>
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf.cnf
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/web2c/tex/tex.fmt
INPUT igortest.tex
OUTPUT igortest.log
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/texfonts.map
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/texfonts.map
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/times/ptmr8r.tfm
OUTPUT igortest.dvi
```

The `texfonts.map` file is an “extension” of TeX that makes it possible to alias some TFM file names (currently used only for the “circle fonts” used by LaTeX in picture mode, that in the past suffered from name changes). So you see that the TFM file *is* loaded. As other have already answered, the data from `cmr10.tfm` is already stored in the format, so it's loaded into memory at job start.

Next, let's look at `igortest.dvi` with `dvitype`:

```
This is DVItype, Version 3.6 (TeX Live 2014)
Options selected:
  Starting page = * 
  Maximum number of pages = 1000000
  Output level = 4 (the works)
  Resolution = 300.00000000 pixels per inch
numerator/denominator=25400000/473628672
magnification=1000;       0.00006334 pixels per DVI unit
' TeX output 2015.04.17:1112'
Postamble starts at byte 140.
maxv=43725786, maxh=30785863, maxstackdepth=2, totalpages=1
Font 50: ptmr8r---loaded at size 655360 DVI units 

42: beginning of page 1 
87: push 
level 0:(h=0,v=0,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0,hh=0,vv=0) 
88: down3 -917504 v:=0-917504=-917504, vv:=-58 
92: pop 
level 0:(h=0,v=0,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0,hh=0,vv=0) 
93: down4 42152922 v:=0+42152922=42152922, vv:=2670 
98: push 
level 0:(h=0,v=42152922,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0,hh=0,vv=2670) 
99: down4 -41497562 v:=42152922-41497562=655360, vv:=42 
104: push 
level 1:(h=0,v=655360,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0,hh=0,vv=42) 
105: right3 1310720 h:=0+1310720=1310720, hh:=83 
[ ]
109: fntdef1 50: ptmr7t 
131: fntnum50 current font is ptmr7t 
132: setchar97 h:=1310720+290976=1601696, hh:=101 
[a]
133: pop 
level 1:(h=0,v=655360,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0,hh=0,vv=42) 
134: pop 
level 0:(h=0,v=42152922,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0,hh=0,vv=2670) 
135: down3 1572864 v:=42152922+1572864=43725786, vv:=2770 
139: eop
```

The DVI file doesn't contain the metric information about the used fonts; the needed information has already been used by TeX when setting boxes, after applying kerns and ligatures.

On the other hand, DVI driver may look for and read the TFM files, because they could contain essential information for them. This happens for `dvips`, as

```
dvips -d -1 igortest.dvi 2>igortest.dls
```

produces a file containing

```
kdebug:fopen(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/times/ptmr8r.tfm, rb) => 0x7fff7d7f5338
kdebug:fclose(0x7fff7d7f5338) => 0
```

(note that `-d -1` is similar to the `-recorder` option, see the manual of Kpathsea for more information).

I won't report the complete log with `dvipdfmx --kpathsea-debug -1 igortest 2>igortest.dls` either. However, the line

```
kdebug:search([ptmr7t.tfm]) => /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/times/ptmr7t.tfm
```

tells us that also `dvipdfmx` reads the TFM file.

Note that also `dvitype` looks for the TFM file as witnessed by

```
kdebug:fopen(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/times/ptmr8r.tfm, rb) => 0x7fff7d7f5338
kdebug:fclose(0x7fff7d7f5338) => 0
```

obtained in a similar way as before.

Comment: Your answer is confusable because the `ptmr7t` isn't direct font, but virtual font. This means that there is more complications. I don't believe the `-d32` option but I am using `strace -o trac dvips ignoretest.dvi`. You can look into `trac` file and you can see that `ptmr7t.vf` is opened, then `ptmr8r.tfm` is opened (because `ptmr7t.vf` points to `ptmr8r`) and finally based on the file `psfonts.map` (no `texfonts.map`) the files `8r.enc` and `utmr8a.pfb` are opened (see the line which begins by `ptmr8r`).  Conclusion: `dvips` *needs* the metric for more checks as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @wipet Thanks for noting; I changed `ptmr7t` to `ptmr8r` which is not virtual.

Comment: And `ptmr8r.tfm` is loaded by `dvips`. Your sentence "You see that dvips doesn't need to load the TFM file" is incorrect.

Comment: @wipet Already fixed; it seems that `-d 32` is not really reliable.

Comment: `dvipdfmx --kpathsea-debug -1 ...` gives this error: `dvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid kpathsearch debugging flags specified: -1` (TL on Debian 8)

Comment: @IgorLiferenko So what?

Comment: I just wanted to know if it is something wrong with my dvipdfmx.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko seems a bug in `dvipdfmx` (and `xdvipdfmx` as well).

Answer (score 5):

The `tfm` information is saved in `.fmt` file when `tex -ini` is run.

The `dvi` output includes

- the shifts (numerically specified by internal unit) of current typesetting point. These commands are used at inter-word spaces, inter-letter kerns and at other vertical/horizontal spaces generated by TeX)
- the commands about typesetting the characters from the slots of the font. These commands doesn't specify the shift of the current typesetting point after the character is typeset. It is assumed that the `dvi` driver will be know the character width.

The same is in PostScript: When `(text) show` command is used in PostScript then the `t` is typeset and the current typesetting point is shifted by the width of `t`. This information is saved in outlines `.pfb` format of fonts as `wx` parameter.

`xdvi` uses these PostScript fonts from `pfb`, so it knows the character width and it can realize the `dvi` without re-reading the `tfm`. But `dvipdfmx` (or `dvips`) does more checks if all data is consistent, so it reads the `tfm` file again.

Comment: It's curious that `dvitype` loads the TFM file and `xdvi` doesn't. Probably `dvitype` has a more thorough check that the developers of `xdvi` didn't deem necessary.

Comment: @egreg The `WX` parameter (read from `pfb` files) includes the character widths in 1/1000 quad units, but `tfm` includes the character width in 1/2^16 pt units, i.e more precisely. IMHO, the author of `xdvi` program decided that the less precision is sufficient for screen devices but printing devices (used after `dvips`) need the corrections.

Comment: @wipet: You say: "tfm includes the character width in 1/2^16 pt units" (1/2^16 pt is one dvi unit), but dvitype shows "setchar65 h:=0+491521"; and web2c manual says about dvitype output: 'h' and 'v' define the current position in DVI units. In PL file width of letter A is 0.750002. So, in tfm file dimensions are not dvi units. What are they?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko I simplified my information about tfm, sorry. Of course, dvi uses this precision. But tfm works with decimal numbers in four bytes where decimal point is in the middle of the second byte (between 12-th and 13-th bit). I. e. when the four bytes includes a, b, c, d (integers) then the number is 2^4*a+2^{-4}*b+2^{-12}*c+2^{-20}*d. And these numbers represent the multiplies of design_size (in cmr10.tfm is design_size=10pt). Finally, these numbers are represented by *decimal digits* when tftpl, pltotf are used. This brings the rounding.  My TeXbook naruby describes this in detail.

Comment: @wipet: You say `vertical/horizontal spaces` - please give an example how vertical space is corrected. I tried to do this in this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289986/why-xdvi-does-not-correct-heights-from-pfb-files, but cannot achieve the same results as with horizontal spaces. This is important, because in CS-fonts height of letter É, for example, is wrong - see this example https://www.dropbox.com/s/rf4w3asvk4fzq4x/metrics.tex?dl=0