# What are exact rules of reading TFM files?

Tags: fonts

This question is connected with the answers to this question: [How TeX creates DVI without reading TFM file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239067/how-tex-creates-dvi-without-reading-tfm-file)

Let's modify only TFM file for cmr10 (and change the font name, of course), leaving all the rest font-related files unchanged:

```
tftopl cmr10.tfm > mycmr10.vpl
patch <<EOF
--- mycmr10.vpl
+++ mycmr10.vpl
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+(MAPFONT D 0 (FONTNAME cmr10))
 (FAMILY CMR)
 (FACE O 352)
 (CODINGSCHEME TEX TEXT)
@@ -466,7 +467,7 @@
    (CHARHT R 0.694445)
    )
 (CHARACTER C A
-   (CHARWD R 0.750002)
+   (CHARWD R 0.4)
    (CHARHT R 0.683332)
    (COMMENT
       (KRN C t R -0.027779)
EOF
vptovf mycmr10.vpl
```

Test new metric:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{A}
\showbox0
\font\myfont=mycmr10\myfont
\setbox0=\hbox{A}
\showbox0
```

The output confirms that the new metric works:

```
\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x7.50002
\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x3.99998
```

Now compile this test.tex

```
\font\myfont=mycmr10\myfont
Ab
\bye
```

In the output of xdvi, dvips and dvipdfmx letters overlap. So, all of them nevertheless read TFM file? Although ouput of dvips does not indicate this,  and xdvi should not do this.

Comment: I changed font metrics without changing the font deliberately - to test if TFM file is read or not.

Comment: the dvi will reference the virtual font so all the dvi drivers will need to load the virtual font so the overlap will result in them mapping from there to the underlying real font cnmr10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mycmr10.vf` file includes your new character width. So `xdvi` knows this from this source and the characters are overlap. But `xdvi` doesn't read the `cmr10.tfm` file (as mentioned in the previous thread).

You can try this in your working directory:

```
tftopl cmr10.tfm > cmr10.pl
```

edit cmr10.pl in order the character A has different width.

```
pltotf cmr10.pl
```

Now you have "bad metric" `cmr10.tfm` in your working directory. Generate format:

```
tex -ini plain
\dump
```

use format:

```
tex -fmt plain \\relax Ab\\end
```

Then `xdvi texput` shows non-overlapping characters (because it puts the characters by character widths read from `cmr10.pfb`) but `dvips` and `dvipdfmx` reads your changed metric and does the correction of the characters: they overlap.

Comment: What is curious: in this example, if we do not regenerate the format (to use new metric in it), the results will be the same anyway.

Comment: This is not curious, this only shows the principle of dvi format mentioned in my previous thread: The dvi includes "put A, then put b" without numerical specifications of shifts. And dvips reads TFM and decides, what does it mean "put A, then put b". But if you does not regenerate format then TeX calculates "Ab" couple as normal and different behavior can be seen at the end of lines and when paragraph breaking algorithm processes the words with the A letter.