# Why xdvi does not correct heights from pfb files?

Tags: fonts, plain-tex, xdvi

In your working directory:

```
$ tftopl cmr10.tfm > cmr10.pl
```

Change `cmr10.pl` n order the character A has different width and B has different height:

```
--- cmr10.pl.orig
+++ cmr10.pl
@@ -466,7 +466,7 @@
    (CHARHT R 0.694445)
    )
 (CHARACTER C A
-   (CHARWD R 0.750002)
+   (CHARWD R 0.1)
    (CHARHT R 0.683332)
    (COMMENT
       (KRN C t R -0.027779)
@@ -483,7 +483,7 @@
    )
 (CHARACTER C B
    (CHARWD R 0.708336)
-   (CHARHT R 0.683332)
+   (CHARHT R 0.1)
    )
 (CHARACTER C C
    (CHARWD R 0.722224)
```

Create "bad metric" cmr10.tfm in your working directory:

```
$ pltotf cmr10.pl
```

Generate format:

```
$ pdftex -ini '\input plain \dump'
```

Create test documents:

```
$ pdftex -fmt plain -jobname wd \\pdfoutput=1 Ab\\end
$ pdftex -fmt plain -jobname wd \\pdfoutput=0 Ab\\end
$ pdftex -fmt plain -jobname ht \\pdfoutput=1 x\\par\\nointerlineskip B\\end
$ pdftex -fmt plain -jobname ht \\pdfoutput=0 x\\par\\nointerlineskip B\\end
```

Compare `wd.dvi` with `wd.pdf` and then `ht.dvi` with `ht.pdf` - why width are corrected by xdvi, and heights are not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose that your question is: why `wd.dvi` is displayed by `xdvi` without `tfm` correction but all others experiments show the correction.

Widths of all characters are copied in the `pfb` font file, namely the command `hsbw` uses the left side-bearing and width values. You can try to do

```
t1disasm cmr10.pfb > cmr10.pps
```

and look into `cmr10.pps` at the character `/A`. The `32 750 hsbw` is here. So the `A` has 750/1000 em width and it is irrelevant that different `tfm` metric were used. Xdvi uses these data. The `dvi` typesetting commands are "print A, then print b" without any correction between it.

On the other hand, the `wd.pdf` respects the corrected `tfm`. Why? You can use `\pdfcompresslevel=0` in order to see more information in pdf file (using normal text editor). And what we see here? First. The command `[(Ab)] TJ` is here, so the printing commands are the same: "print A, then print b". The font CMR10 is downloaded. You can cut the font data (from `stream` to `endstream` without them) and apply the `t1disasm`. Then you can see that the font is loaded partially, only letters `/A`, `/b` and digit `/one`. And the `32 750 hsbw` is for the `/A` letter. Why the PDF viewer knows that corrected metris were used? Because there is a next object with the data `[500 500 500 ... 555.6]`. The widths from the first character `/one=49`, to `/b=98` are here. You can see that the 17th number is 100. This is the width of `/A` from corrected `tfm` metric. PdfTeX copies data from used metric to this object into the PDF output and PDF viewer uses them.

And why the experiments with heights gives correct results (using corrected metric) anyway? Because `pfb` fonts does not include height metric data and all vertical shifts are exactly performed by the printing commands (in `dvi` or in `PDF`).